# .csv file not connecting through API In Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Web Data Connector In Tableau so that i can connect a .csv through API with tableau.

http://starschema.github.io/tableau-web-table-connector/dist/csv.html

It has a sample file in it which is working fine but when iam trying to insert my .csv file it is showing error i.e.

Error while trying to load ' http://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/tables/csv/c1-data.csv'.
The table "[TableauTemp].[webdata-direct.1msv6ys1ymx5ob1d0o50i1i58owp]" does not exist.

Does anyone know that what is the issue here, and can help me with this thanks

Comment: Hey Ankit - First off, sweet connector! Will be super useful, I would definitely encourage you to share it with the community if you'd like (http://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/community/).  I looked at this and found this error message in the logs: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/tables/csv/c1-data.csv. Origin http://starschema.github.io is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin".  So this appears to be a CORS issues, more info here: http://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/docs/wdc_cors

Comment: @lbrendanl thank you mate.But this connector is not made by me and it is already shared with the tableau community as far as i know.so thanks for your suggestion and for giving your valuable time..